# Add users to google group automatically from excel sheet

Tags: python, excel

I have list of users on excel sheet and each month there are new users added to the excel sheet.  My question is how to add these users from excel sheet into google mailing group( I have a google group which I use to communicate with these users) automatically.  Currently I have been performing this process manually but I would like to automate this process.

Lets say I will be using python to automate this process, then my question is "whats the command to add these users to the group"? and would this command will work with OS?

I heard that using Admin SDK this could be possible but I think my case is little different.   I am admin of the google group (this group is set up by corporate ID)  but I am not admin of the entire console and we don't know who is the main admin.
Could I still be able to add users to google group automatically  just by being the admin of that group using Admin SDK?

Thanks, 
Rahul

Comment: There is no command to do this; you'll need to write a program.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Groups API add Member](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21253849/google-groups-api-add-member)